# What could be the potential causes for the issue where an API fetch operation fails to retrieve data from URL in, and how can this problem be solved?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cors

I am trying to fetch information from the server in the frontend. Here is how i fetch user details. It doesn't work.

```
const UserDetails = async () => {
  const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

  try {
    console.log(`${apiUrl}`);
    console.log("fetching");
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/user/getUserDetails`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`response was not ok. Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const data = await response.json();

    return data.userDetails;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    throw err;
  }
};

export default UserDetails;
```

However it works when i put the url as proxy in package.json and put as const response = await fetch(`/api/user/getUserDetails`);.
Still my login,which fetches the same way works.

```
export const useLogin = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null);
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext();
  const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
  const login = async (email, password) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    console.log("login request made", email, password);
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/user/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    const userRole = json.userRole;
    console.log("User Role:", userRole);

    if (!response.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(json.error);
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("logging in", json);
      // save the user to local storage
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(json));

      // update the auth context
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: { ...json, role: userRole } });

      // update loading state
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { login, isLoading, error };
};
```

below is my .env file

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:4000
```

My server.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const bookRoutes = require("./routes/Book");
const publisherrightRoutes = require("./routes/Publisherright");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_51O12iqAQvidGp1QOJDPSU2UlOCAjNtA8CPjbH4X6RssKvOKxLCuuflXvlHfLEWXBg4U4UIIL4Wypv74pFmrFDGXQ00qNuRF96x"
);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

//middlware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

//routes
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/book", bookRoutes);
app.use("/api/publisherright", publisherrightRoutes);

app.post("/create-subscription", async (req, res) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email,
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
  });

  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{ plan: req.body.plan }],
  });

  res.json({ subscription });
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
      console.log("Connected to db and  listening on port ", process.env.PORT);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I tried putting console logs and it doesn't fetch.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/

Comment: when i use proxy method the request seems to be going to http://localhost:3000/api/user/getUserDetails but when i use the apiUrl env it calls
http://localhost:4000/api/user/getUserDetails

Answer (score 0):

This has to do something with the cookies and cors
add credentials:"include" in every fetch request

```js
 const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/user/getUserDetails`,credentials:"include",);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).